Any Linux Distros - on cgroups v2, what happens if my resource exceeds the working_set memory limit?
before hand: I asked this question on Kubernetes and I was told that it's the Linux kernel that actually evaluates and decides
On K8S I can only generically set the Limits of memory for my pod, but under the hood, we have rss and working_set. For my applications (mostly .net) the working_set is always superior.
I'm looking for a authoritative answer for "what will happen if my pod WORKING SET memory exceeds the LIMITS?" can anyone help me? something like "according to these lines of code here, cgroups v2 will do X" would be perfect!
If your answer is pertaining only a single Distro, please state which one.
